# Looping generated array, assigning it to variable trying to return as a whole

Tags: php

I have a function that generates array so I can do it like this further:

```
while ($this->stmt->fetch()) // $row is generated here
{
   .....
}
```

If I write in this while loop `print_r($row)` it works fine shows different arrays

But.. If I write in there `$return[] = $row` then `$return` array has all duplicate entries inside

How is that possible? I'm very exhausted and can't figure it out.

**Update**

```
public function bind_array($stmt, &$row)
{
      $md = $stmt->result_metadata();

      $params = array();
      while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
         $params[] = &$row[$field->name];   
      }

   call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
}

public function results($method = 'assoc', $close_stmt = false)
{
   $this->bind_array($this->stmt, $row);

   while ($this->stmt->fetch())
   {
      $ret[] = $row; // if write here print_r($row) instead everything is good
   }
   print_r($ret); // all are duplicate, 'id' are same, etc..
}
```

Comment: Would help to see a bit more code to make a determination to your problem.

Comment: You claim that `$row` is generated somewhere, and that it can be printed, but we do not see actual code doing this. And because you have the problem with what happens afterwards, it would be helping if we know about it.

Comment: Plus if I do `$ret[] = $row['id']` then `print_r($ret)` prints correctly > Different IDs. BUT, i can't rely on this, because in reality work is done with unknown array keys.

Comment: foreach will do miracles with that last comment problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how but I solved it like this:

```
while ($this->stmt->fetch())
{
    foreach ($row as $k => $v)
    {
        $r[$k] = $v;
    }
    $ret[] = $r;
}

print_r($ret); // It gave different results, finally!
```

Comment: `$r[] = $v` (empty brackets) appends to the array, `$r[$k] = $v` is setting a specific index to a value, which would be where the overwrite comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea and I think more simple (filling an array with arrays);

```
// $row = array("foo" => "the foo");
foreach ($row as $k => $v) $ret[] = array($k => $v);
```

Gives;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => the foo
        )

)
```